# How to show sqlite db data as multi columns view in QTableView Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I've a sqlite db with large data. All data is collected as one column in db.

Now I want to show data as table (eg. 7 columns and many rows that from db).

How can I show data in QTableView? (please see picture)

[image: table as sample data]

Comment: Use QSqlQTableModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QSqlTableModel like this:

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, database);
model->setTable("employee");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Salary"));

QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(model);
view->hideColumn(0); // don't show the ID
view->show();
```

See more in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html)

Comment: He want same column data spanning across multiple columns and multiple rows

Comment: Yes I want same column data spanning across multiple columns and multiple rows